# Designing Phones Clay Model

Tags: mockup

Are there any tutorials for making phone clay designs and on how to give a perspective view like the image below.

Or any one can point me in the right direction. I know there are mock ups that I can use but want to learn the process of doing so.

[image]

Comment: This would be pretty simple In any 3D application, even for a beginner, since it doesn't really have any small details. There are probably plenty of tutorials for any 3D application on how make an iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

***If*** you decide to do this in a **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) modeling app (@Danielillo's Illustrator-based answer is excellent, BTW) you have a couple of different possible routes: one is to poly model this by starting with a cube or rectangle primitive, then bevel the vertical corner edges to get that lozenge plan shape, then subsequently bevel all edges to round them all to your preference.

Basic Rectangle - vertical edges selected.
[image]

Vertical edges being beveled.
[image]

Top and bottom face edges being beveled to a smaller radius.
[image]

Resulting geometry.
[image]

Preview render running during modeling.
[image]

Quick bucket render having added the round button.
[image]

*If* the **3D DCC** app you're using supports *subdivision surface* modeling, you could shorten the modeling time a lot by making a rectangle of the right proportions, and either add some hold edges or paint some edge weights, and then subdivide the rectangle to 2 or 3 levels.

In the super-quick poly-modeling example above, I gave the mesh a simple material on the screen area which could be composited in post to display your interface design, which is how it looks as though your example was done.

For my own work, I *tend* to apply the design image as a substrate with the material set to luminous, and the image to luminous colour, and give it a clearcoat, and assign a softbox light to create a reflection so that you get a sense of the interface design being on a live phone in a photo. This also allows you to do things like stack phones and have appropriate reflections showing without then being forced to do a bunch of post work.

The image below is one I did in 2014 of a Samsung Galaxy phone - and yes, on that example I spent a lot more time on the modeling process and material development, as that was half the focus of the piece.

[image]

And in case you're curious - here's that same setup, from the same camera position - wireframe. This one was a sub-D model... to get nice curves without super-high polycounts. At the time, I owned a Samsung Galaxy S4, so I had ample opportunity to niggle and get it right. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Using Illustrator

### Case

Make a rectangle with rounded corners, filled white, and apply **3D Extrude & Bevel**

[image: 3D Extrude]

### Shadow

- Use the same rectangle filled black and apply **3D Rotate**, the same
  degrees like the case 3D.
- **Menu Effect** > **Stylize** > **Feather**. Define Multiply mode and reduce the Opacity from the **Transparency Panel**.

[image: shadow]

### Top Objects

Make a rectangle and a circle and apply **3D Rotate**, the same degrees like the case 3D

[image: Objects]

### Assemble

[image]